# Loading dynamic quote in IE with php/js - can't seem to override the cache

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, caching

I've set up a basic script which loads a random quote into a web page, pulling the quote from a list in a php file. It works fine in Firefox and Safari, but in Internet Explorer users always see the same quote and refreshing the page will not change the quote.

I've narrowed this down to a cache issue in IE, as when I go into F12 Developer tools in IE 9 and set cache to always refresh from server, the issue goes away. However, I want visitors to the site to see a changing quote.

I have tried adding this to the page header with no luck:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

I also saw this question: [How do I stop js files being cached in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928398/how-do-i-stop-js-files-being-cached-in-ie) and I added a timestamp to the .js file which holds the script but this didn't change anything.

Anything else I might be missing? The .js file is very simple:

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
$j("#quoteContainer").load("/quote_generator.php", "quote=emotion");
});
```

The quote generator, simplified, gets the type of quote (emotion in this case) and displays it:

```
$quotes[] = 'emotion quote.';
$quotes[] = 'emotion quote2.';
$random_number = rand(0,count($quotes)-1);
echo $quotes[$random_number];
```

Would it possibly be caching the PHP file or its output also? Certainly when I adjust the php file the changes don't show until I clear the IE cache?

Comment: Solved by Pointy - adding a nonce to the php link was required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe give it a nonce:

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
   $j("#quoteContainer").load("/quote_generator.php", {quote: "emotion", nonce: new Date().getTime()});
});
```

(The timestamp isn't the best nonce in the world but it's an easy example.) Your server code will ignore the parameter but it'll make the URL seem unique to the browser cache.

*edit* — sorry it's been a while since I've used `.load()`; if you want to stick with HTTP "GET" requests, you have to give the args as a string (which, imo, is kind-of a questionable API design on jQuery's part but whatever):

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
   $j("#quoteContainer").load("/quote_generator.php", "quote=emotion&nonce=" + new Date().getTime());
});
```

Comment: Is there a syntax issue? I tried this but I don't get any output from my php file. In the php file it looks for the quote as a   GET:  switch($_GET['quote']) {
     case "emotion";

Comment: Well I *think* that `.load()` always uses HTTP GET. Check with Firebug or something to make sure the HTTP request looks the way you think it should.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much. Turns out that adding the nonce turned this into a POST request somehow. Once I'd adjusted my PHP to account for this it worked like a charm.

Comment: Huh that's weird.  Well it's been a while since I coded with ".load()".  I'll see if I can find a way to force it back to GET and I'll add another comment or update the answer.

Comment: OK answer updated; it has to do with my use of an object literal for the arguments, which I did semi-consciously out of habit with other APIs.  If you use a string (like your original or my update), it should do a GET instead of a POST.